How to specify button badge information for accessibility in iOS
I have a custom button related to user notifications in my app which can have a numberic badge. If there is no badge, I want the VoiceOver to speak "Notifications. Button" and if it has a badge (with 3 notifications for example), I want VoiceOver to speak "Notifications. You have new notifications. Button".
The speak of ". Button" is acomplished by using accessibilityTraits = .button. But what would be the correct way to make VoiceOver speak "You have new notifications"?

Include this text in the accessibilityLabel
Use the accessibilityValue -> Strictly speaking, it refers to the value but this field should be used for textFields or sliders
Use accessibilityHint -> As Apple doc says it should be used to provide a brief description of what happens when performing an action related to this element


You can use accessbilityLabel and change the value conditionally
Or, you can put "You have new notifications", into accessibilityValue. Which would make sense, since its value varies in different situations. Additionally, this way, you don't have to touch accessibilityLabel
